# Show that every function is integrable in a nonempty space with Dirac's measure.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $\delta_a$ the Dirac measure $(a \in X)$. Show that every function $f$ is integrable and that 
>   $$\int_X f \delta_a = f(a)$$

For the second part, I first assumed that $f :X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$. Then there exists an increasing sequence $(s_n)_n$ of simple functions such that $\lim_n s_n = f$, and also, we have that 
$$\int_X f \delta_a = \lim_n \int_X s_n \delta_a$$
So for a fixed $n$, $s_n$ has a representation of the form 
$$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i\chi_{A_i}$$
where $A_1 \cap A_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$. Then
$$\int_X s_n \delta_a = \sum_{i=i}^ma_i \delta_a(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\chi_{A_i} = s_n(a)$$
Therefore, taking limits, since $(s_n)_n \rightarrow f$, we have the result. For non negative functions $f: X \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ I believe it will be the same applied to its positive and negative part $f^+$ and $f^-$.

If this is fine (which I'm unsure of), I'm just left with the first part, that so far I have been unable to prove. A function $f :X \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ is integrable if the integral exists and is finite, or if $\int_X |f| < \infty$. Any hint on how to proceed would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suppose a function in this context would have $\mathbb R$ as codomain, for otherwise one could pick an infinite value at $a$, making it non-integrable. Your work on the exercise looks correct to me, though.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Thank you! That's what I thought, but the exercise didn't give much context on that matter.